# WAS 8.5 The enterprise bean in the ejb.jar module has no EJB type defined. (ejb 2.x -> 3.x)

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

Im migrating our deployment descriptors from EJB 2.x to EJB version 3.x. Currently im getting the following error:

```
[exec]   [wsadmin] com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: 
com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: 
The MyBean enterprise bean in the ejb.jar module has no EJB type defined.
```

Now according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83725/xml1.htm this is my ejb-jar.xml element for the enterprise bean definition:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session id="MyBean">
        <ejb-name>MyBean</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>foo.MyBean</ejb-class>
        <env-entry>
            <description>
            </description>
            <env-entry-name>bootloader.config</env-entry-name>
            <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
            <env-entry-value>my_config</env-entry-value>
        </env-entry>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

The above element "session" should define the beans type which is session since the according Class it implements the javax.ejb.SessionBean interface.

Am i missing anything here already? Or do i have to adjust the bean class itself as well when migrating those deployment descriptors?

Best Regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it out. I forgot the websphere specific deployment descriptor which now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
             xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.1">

     <session name="MyBean" simple-binding-name="MyBean">
      <resource-ref name="jms/foo/" binding-name="jms/foo"/>
     </session>

</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

And now i was able to deploy the application.

Comment: I have set this as the accepted answer since it solved my issue back when it occured. There however are probably other more general reasons for this issue to occour so feel free to add a more general answer (like a checklist of what it could be) and i will switch it to the accepted answer since mine basicially just says "it has somethign to do with the deployment descriptors format which you have to read about by yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.

The fix for me was adding the "@Stateless" annotation above the class name:

```
@Stateless
public class XxxxBean implements YyyyService
```

I realise this is an old thread but I hope this helps somebody :).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not correct. You need either do define '@Stateless' or create <session> entry in ejb-jar.xml. Not both.